# Boosting input fields for completion suggester

Tags: search, full-text-search, elasticsearch

Im using completion suggester for autocomplete.. These are my documents

```
/* doc 1 */
{
    Title: CineMAX: Inorbit Mall, Cyberabad
    Suggest: {
        input: [
            CineMAX:
            Inorbit
            Mall
            Cyberabad
            CineMAX: Inorbit Mall, Cyberabad
        ]
        output: CineMAX: Inorbit Mall, Cyberabad
        payload: {
        ....
        }
        weight: 1
    }
}

/* doc 2 */
{
    Title: INOX: Kolkata
    Suggest: {
        input: [
            INOX:
            Kolkata
            INOX: Kolkata
        ]
        output: INOX: Kolkata 
        payload: {
            ....
        }
        weight: 1
    }
}
```

Im using completion query as below

```
{
    "suggestion":{
       "text":"inox",
       "completion":{
           "field":"Suggest",
           "fuzzy":{
               "edit_distance":1,
               "transpositions":true,
               "prefix_length":1,
               "min_length":4
           }
       }

    }       
}
```

But here i am getting the output as

1. CineMAX: Inorbit Mall, Cyberabad,
2. INOX: Kolkata

I want to give more priority to exact match.. so i  want  **INOX: Kolkata** in the top..

I have splitted the title using php explode().. so i can match middle words also..I don know how to boost specific words in the title..Plz help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: What mappings and analyzers are set on this index?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running two completion queries like this:

```
{
    "text": "inox",
    "suggestion_not_fuzzy": {
       "completion": {
           "field": "Suggest"
       }
    },
    "suggestion_fuzzy": {
       "completion": {
           "field": "Suggest",
           "fuzzy": {
               "edit_distance": 1,
               "transpositions": true,
               "prefix_length": 1,
               "min_length": 4
           }
       }
    }
}
```

and then try to get the results from "suggestion_not_fuzzy", if empty fallback to "suggestion_fuzzy"

Answer (score 1):

What you want is give more weight to the document that has the shortest title. If two documents match your query, the one with the shortest title means that with less information, it was still found so it has to have a higher score.

What you can do is at index time, set :

```
weight = 1000 - number_of_characters_of_document_title (1000 or any other number : was just trying to have a positive weight)
```